# $K_0$ ring of del-pezzo surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, blowup

Is there book or paper where described structure of $K_0$ ring of a del-pezzo surfaces? Especially in case of the blowup of projective line in three points.
I know method for computing $K_0$ ring of blowup but it's computationally heavy and i'm afraid of making a mistake.

Comment: $K_0$ and the Chow groups are pretty close to each other and it is trivial to calculate the Chow group for the plane blown up at a few points. For example, if you blow up $n$ points on the plane, $CH^0=\mathbb{Z}$, $CH^1$ is the free abelian group generated by the exceptional divisors $E_i$ and the pull back of a general hyperplane $H$. $CH^2$ is the free abelian group generated by a point $P$. The multiplication is just given by intersection numbers. For example $E_i\cdot E_j=E_i\cdot H=0$ for $i\neq j$. $E_i^2=-P$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the blowup of a plane at points $P_1$, \dots, $P_n$ with the corresponding exceptional divisors $E_1$, \dots, $E_n$. Let $H$ be the pullback of the line class from the plane to $X$. Then 
$$
O, O(H), O(2H), O_{E_1}, \dots, O_{E_n}
$$
is a full exceptional collection, hence the corresponding classes
$$
[O], [O(H)], [O(2H)], [O_{E_1}], \dots, [O_{E_n}]
$$
form a basis in $K_0$.

To understand the multiplication note that there are exact sequences
$$
0 \to O((t-3)H) \to O((t-2)H)^{\oplus 3} \to O((t-1)H)^{\oplus 3} \to O(tH) \to 0
$$
for each $t$ (this is a twist of the pullback of the Koszul complex), 
that allows to express inductively all $[O(tH)]$ from $[O]$, $[O(H)]$, $[O(2H)]$,
and
$$
0 \to O \to O(H)^{\oplus 2} \to O(2H) \to O_P \to 0
$$
(again the pullback from the plane) that allows to express $[O_P]$.

After that you can write 
$$
[O(aH)] \cdot [O(bH)] = [O((a+b)H)],\ 
[O(aH)] \cdot [O_{E_i}] = [O_{E_i}],\ 
[O_{E_i}] \cdot [O_{E_j}] = -\delta_{ij}[O_P].
$$